# i want two columns value in different table in mysql and each table i apply different condition

Tags: c#, mysql

i have two table. table1 and table2.each table is having three columns.
each table columnsname is different.i apply the query for  table .i want one columns value for table1
and i want two columns value for table2.i want to write one query for each table and apply different condition for each table.but ,i want to result in only one query

Comment: Can you please provide the table definitions, sample data & what you want the results to look like? Or at least update the question with real table names?

Comment: what does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use joins , it can be retrived

select table1.colname,table2.colname from table1, table2
where  table2.colname=table2.colname.

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate to results with `union`

```
select col1 as A, col2 as B, col3 as C from table1 where col1 = 'foo'
union all
select colA as A, colB as B, colC as C from table2 where colB = 'bar'
```

Comment: This deserves a +1 just for understanding what the OP wants. On a side note, use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: don't think so, your query will return a staggered list anyway nice guess work hope the OP clarifies :P

Answer (score 0):

SELECT tbl1.columnName,tbl2.columnName1,tbl2.columnName2 
FROM table1 tbl1
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT columnName1,columnName2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.field_fk = tbl1.filedId
)tbl2